# How to create new column based on values on list in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
--------
John Simon prd
agc Ann White
BeN and Ann

bad_list = ["Ben", "Wayne"]
```

And I need to ake something like: create new column "col2" and if value in "col1" has value from bad_list give "1" in "col2" for this row and 0 if not.

Be aware thatn size of letter in bad_list and "col1" should be ignored, for example in "col1" is value "BeN" and on bad_list is "Ben" so it should also have value "1" in "col2"

So as a result based on Data Frame and conditions above I need as a result like below:

```
col1            | col2
----------------|------
John Simon prd  |0
arc Ann White   |0
BeN and Ann     |1
```

last row in "col2" has value "1" because "Ben" is on bad_list nevermind that in "col1" is written as BeN. How can I do that in Python Pandas?

I aware that it could be similar question to other but i checked orher questions and answers are not correct for example in terms of size of letters.

Comment: You might want to emphasize the difference between this question and your previous, because currently they look very similar.

Comment: I closed your other question since this is a duplicate, please dont repost it

Comment: Erfan, but question that you think is similar is not similar!!!!!!!! because question that you recommend concern solution which do niot take into account size of letter

Comment: open this question please

Comment: @gato  I have provided some hint in your last question:  add `flags=re.IGNORECASE` in `str.contains()` call.